# Is there any way of putting two navigation graphs into separate scaffolds in Jetpack Compose?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack, android-jetpack-navigation

I am trying to build a multi-step onboarding for my Android app using Jetpack Compose and its navigation module.

My setup of choice would be to have two separate navigation graphs. One for the onboarding and another one for the main experience.
The onboarding needs a scaffold with a top bar and the main experience has a tab bar.

Is there any way of putting each `navigation` graph into its own `Scaffold` while preserving to only have one `NavHost`?

I have tried that but I am not able to do something like that:

```
NavHost(navController = navController, Destinations.Onboarding.welcome) {
    navigation(Destinations.Onboarding.welcome, Destinations.Onboarding.graph) {
         Scaffold(...)
         // all of the composable(route = "something") should go inside of the scaffold
    }
    navigation(Destinations.Main.dashboard, Destinations.Main.graph) {
         Scaffold(...)
         // all of the composable(route = "something") should go inside of the scaffold
    }
}
```

Is there any way of achieving what I want or do you have any tips on how to build such a setup?

Comment: So the only part of the Scaffold that is actually different is the `topBar` part? You just want to swap out the contents of that based on what graph you are on? Or by "tabs" do you mean tabs you'd put in the `bottomBar` part?

Comment: Onboarding should only have a `topBar` with content related to the onboarding and the main experience only has a `bottomBar` with items navigating to different screens. I could show or hide them based on the current route but tbh this feels like a major hack and it also does not feel like the right separation of concerns.

Comment: If your source of truth for 'should this be displayed' is based on what screen you are in, why does using that source of truth for your if check or `AnimatedVisibility` state seem like a hack? That seems like very typical [state hoisting](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/state#state-hoisting).